# Split all list of all categories into subcategories? (with Java only)

Tags: java, oop, jpa, collections, dto

We have an entity class and a list of all categories:

```
class Category {
  Long id, parentId;
}
...
List<Category> categoryList = <...>;
```

How to convert to a list of DTOs like this:

```
class CategoryDTO {
  Long id; 
  List<CategoryDTO> subcategories;
}
```

How can this be done without a One-to-One entity relationship?

Comment: Based on `Category` class. There can be objects without parent? If yes, how you mark it? If not, that mean there is an loop, between all of them?

Comment: Obviously there can muliple level right ?

Comment: There can be an indefinite number of levels. The main levels have parentId = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CategoryConverterImpl implements CategoryConverter {
    private CategoryDTO convertEntity(Category s) {
        Long id = s.getId();
        return new CategoryDTO()
                .setId(id)
                .setSubcategories(
                        convertCollection(
                                categoryCollection.stream()
                                        .filter(c -> Objects.equals(c.getParentCategoryId(), id))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        )
                );
    }

    private List<CategoryDTO> convertCollection(Collection<Category> categoryCollection) {
        return categoryCollection.stream()
                .map(this::convertEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Collection<Category> categoryCollection;

    @Override
    public List<CategoryDTO> convert(Collection<Category> categoryCollection) {
        this.categoryCollection = categoryCollection;
        return categoryCollection.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getParentCategoryId() == null)
                .map(this::convertEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<Long, CategoryDTO>` and fill it from `categoryList`, mapping `id` to a `CategoryDTO` created from the `Category` object.

Then loop through `categoryList` again, lookup both `id` and `parentId` in the map, and add to the `subcategories` list as appropriate.

E.g. something like this:

```java
Map<Long, CategoryDTO> categoryDTOs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Category category : categoryList) {
    categoryDTOs.put(category.getId(), new CategoryDTO(category.getId()));
}
for (Category category : categoryList) {
    if (category.getParentId() != null) {
        categoryDTOs.get(category.getParentId())
                    .addSubcategory(categoryDTOs.get(category.getId()));
    }
}
```